# Change value in multidimension associative array PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I must be missing something about how PHP arrays are handled. When I execute the following code:

```
<?php
$ary = array(
  "alpha" => array("A"=>1,"B"=>2,"C"=>3),
  "beta" => array("A"=>7,"B"=>8,"C"=>9)
  );

foreach ($ary as $key => $vals) {
  $vals["B"]=99;
  echo $key."= ".$vals["A"]." ".$vals["B"]." ".$vals["C"]."<br>";
}
echo $ary['alpha']["B"]."<br>";
?>
```

I get:

```
alpha= 1 99 3
beta= 7 99 9
2
```

The change to 99 in each case seems to be lost. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `foreach ($ary as $key => &$vals)`

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that foreach was pass by value by default. Makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change items of array in foreach statement you should pass by reference.

```
foreach ($ary as $key => &$vals) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ary = array(
  "alpha" => array("A"=>1,"B"=>2,"C"=>3),
  "beta" => array("A"=>7,"B"=>8,"C"=>9)
  );

foreach ($ary as $key => $vals) {
  //$vals["B"]= 99;
  $ary[$key]["B"] = 99;
  echo $key."= ".$vals["A"]." ".$vals["B"]." ".$vals["C"]."<br>";
}
echo $ary['alpha']["B"]."<br>";
?>
```